# undefiend state passed into the Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, setstate, react-functional-component

I have a class component that looks like this:

```
interface MyState {
  x_array: number[]
  y_array: number[]
  order_graph_1: number
}

class ItemsContainerOld extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  constructor(props: MyProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      x_array: [],
      y_array: [],
      order_graph_1: 1,
    }
  }

  addingCoordinate(coord: {x: number; y: number}) {
    const new_x_array = this.state.x_array.concat(coord.x)
    const new_y_array = this.state.y_array.concat(coord.y)
    this.setState({
      x_array: new_x_array,
      y_array: new_y_array,
    })
  }

  setOrders(orders: number[]) {
    this.setState({
      order: orders[0],
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        
      >
        <div>
          <div>
            <DrawerOld
              addCoord={this.addCoord.bind(this)}
              resetCoords={this.resetCoords.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={{paddingLeft: '70px', paddingTop: '50px'}}>
            <Initial
              x={this.state.x_array}
              y={this.state.y_array}
              deg={this.state.order_graph_1}
              color={this.color_graph_1}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ItemsContainerOld
```

I changed it to a functional component. However, upon using the functional component, within this component:

```
<Initial x={x_array} y={y_array}
```

I start getting errors like

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

How can I ensure that the correct values reach that component? Here's a **codesandbox**:
https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-thunder-xsbrm?file=/src/ItemsContainerNew.tsx

Comment: You need to track down why your variables are `undefined`. I suggest using the tips in [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get started.

Comment: Also which line causes the error?

Comment: ```if (props.x.length === 0 && props.y.length === 0) {``` in the ```Initial``` file here. https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-thunder-xsbrm?file=/src/ItemsContainerNew.tsx @Code-Apprentice

Comment: I think the quickets fix here is to change your condition to `if (props.x && props.y)`

Comment: The code that you posted here does not have `if (props.x.length === 0 && props.y.length === 0)`.

Comment: If you still haven't solved this, be sure to read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can always check if the value is undefined or not, like :

```
    if(this.props.x.length===undefined){
      return;
    }
```

and if you want, you can use some default value there.

**this is the approach, every time you encounter this you have to put some condition as a workaround or set an initial default value.

Here is my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-perlman-rzwge?file=/src/Initial.tsx:932-973

and react lifecycle you should know:

[image: collected from : https://csharpcorner.azureedge.net/article/components-lifecycle-in-react/Images/Components%20Lifecycle%20In%20React.jpg]

Updated code, completely working : https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-microservice-mw5j6?file=/src/Initial.tsx

Comment: have you tried this : `if(this.props.x.length===undefined){
      return;
    }` and you should provide your functional component code inside file too.. but my solution should work..

Comment: This didn't work for me. My code in the ItemsContainerNew.tsx file is the functional compoennt https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-thunder-xsbrm?file=/src/ItemsContainerNew.tsx

Comment: ItemsContainerNew.tsx is empty, please check from incognito window

Comment: @Jbd check this out, it's working now : https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-microservice-mw5j6?file=/src/Initial.tsx ... **don't forget to check the answer as accepted**

Comment: This gives an error ```Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined```. When I click on the grid, that's not supposed to happen

Comment: This will still fail because `props.x` or `props.y` is undefined

Comment: @Code-Apprentice but that can be solved using the same approach right ?? `if(some_variable===undefined){...}` this is the approach, he can just replicate anywhere, he want... he explicitly mentioned *TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*, so i solved that part...

Comment: Yes an explicit comparison with `undefined` will probably solve the problem...or at least solve the current error. I'm just suggesting that you edit your code to check the value that is actually causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by changing

```
if (props.x.length === 0 && props.y.length === 0)
```

to

```
if (!props.x && !props.y)
```

Although this may cover up a deeper problem. It would be best to figure out why `props.x` or `props.y` is `undefined`.

Comment: but aren't these two opposite things?

Comment: @Jbd Yes, you are correct. Add `!` to fix that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to improve your state initialization.

Try not setting values as `type 'any'`, be more precise, when initializing your `x_array`and `y_array` you could use

```
// Notice that not only the type has changed from "any" to "number[]",
// But the initial value is now an empty array, causing their initial values 
// (and types) to be arrays since their starting point.
// When initialization happens without a starting value like "useState()",
// The state receives the value "undefined" which causes the error.

const [x_array, setXarray] = useState<number[]>([]);
const [y_array, setYattay] = useState<number[]>([]);
```

Comment: I tried doing this but then it would give me the same 'undefined value' errors. Currently, in this sandbox, I am using ItemsContainerOld in the index.js. But I want to use ItemsContainerNew (the functional Component). https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-thunder-xsbrm?file=/src/Initial.tsx

Comment: While this is good practice, it does nothing to fix `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.